# Using earth engine as a processing step for raster data

Tags: google-earth-engine

We have raster data that we want to process using earth engine and then use that data in another cloud environment. All this should happen programmatically. So manual tools like the asset manager are out. I could not find an API to expose its functionality.

Is there an earth engine API we could use to import and export raster data?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to use google earth as a [map/tile provider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_online_map_services). Long long time ago in a galaxy far away, there used to be some years ago this crazy Russian hacker (in the good sense) that had created code to get tiles, however this was not exactly legal, and i am not sure if it is maintained.

If you want to use Google, you should have to go through their APIs (unless there is a solution involving caching in a limited space, e.g. [like this](http://maptilesbuilder.sourceforge.net/)?) and should use some google API [earth-engine](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/), [maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/), ...? (I am a bit rusty on the current satus)

Be also aware that what they provide changes over time and is not / will not be always free.

For alternatives, which are free and open, [this might be helpful for maps](http://www.fubra.com/blog/2011/11/24/google-maps-free-alternatives/) (also google [open street maps](https://www.google.de/search?q=open%20street%20maps)).

Answer (score 0):

All of Earth Engine is API driven, however some portions of the API are easier to access than others.

For automated imports, you can try using the earthengine command line tool, which formats the API calls for you: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/command_line

For exports, the easiest path is using the Python client library and the ee.batch.Export calls.